# Integer multiples of fundamental time period?

Tags: time, frequency, signal-processing, harmonics

If we define harmonics to be positive integer multiple of fundamental frequency

What will we say to positive integer multiples of fundamental period?

Answer (score 1):

Signals whose periods are integer multiples of a given note are generally called [sub-harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undertone_series) of that signal.